# how to find per-user disk-space-usage?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am writing a small tool in which I require to find per-user File-system-memory-usage.

I have to do some clean up activity if file-system usage is crossing certain threshold value.  What is the system call that I can use, so that I could be able to find per user memory usage?

Comment: ... and how do you know which file belongs to which user? Are you basing yourself on location (presence in `/home/usr1`) or on file permissions (`ls -l` user/group output)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in **disk quotas** (which are supported by some, but not all, filesystems). The low-level system call is [quotactl(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/quotactl). Perhaps using the existing tools [quota(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota) and `quotacheck`, `edquota`,  `warnquota`, `quotaon` etc.... might be enough.

If you want to know the memory used by a given process, consider the [getrusage(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) syscall. You can also read pseudo-files under `/proc/self/` or `/proc/1234` for pid 1234. You can also *scan* the `/proc/` (using usual directory scanning routines: [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), looping on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), closing with `closedir`...) for numerical directories (since `/proc/1234/` describes the process of pid 1234). Read more about [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) (e.g. `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/1234/smaps` and `/proc/1234/status` etc). Tou can query the virtual address space of process 1234 by reading the `/proc/1234/status` and `/proc/1234/maps` pseudo-files. Try for example `cat /proc/$$/status` and `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a terminal to query info for your current shell process.

Of course, consider also the [du(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) and [df(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) commands (perhaps invoke them *carefully* thru [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) if you want to get their output). If for whatever reasons you want to recursively scan a file tree (e.g. to count its cumulated used size like `du` does), consider using the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) functions. See also [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) syscalls.

Remember that other processes can (and often do) write to the filesystem while your program is exploring or querying it. And your user could start new processes (perhaps indirectly, e.g. with [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), `at`, `batch`, `ssh` ...) at any time.

Read also a good Linux programming book, perhaps the old [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

> I am writing a small tool in which I require to find per-user File-system-memory-usage.

If you are coding in C on Linux, consider using your clever mix of [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) and [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and [statfs(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html).

Comment: My problem is that when I run `quota`, I get an `operation not permitted`. Why's that? Maybe it's because it's trying to see all users' quota, while I'm only allowed (and interested) in mine.

Comment: This does not answer the question, just go around the question

Comment: Combining `nftw` and `stat` *does* answer the question (for disk  usage). Scanning `/proc/` for `/proc/*/maps` directory answer the question for virtual memory

Comment: The question was quite specific: finding per-user the total disk space ("File-system-memory-usage", setting aside potential rare cases where there might be terminology issues).
I guess the answer could be more helpful if:
1) It focused on that first (paragraph referring to `du`), and then complement with extra stuff;
2) Post specific command lines, explaining what they do (instead of "consider also the du(1)", "perhaps invoke them carefully thru popen(3)" or "consider using the nftw(3) functions").

Answer (score 27):

A simplistic approach would be

```
du -shc /home/*
```

To sort it:

```
du -smc /home/* | sort -n
```

There is also a wellknown Perl script that has the option of mailing disk usage reports per user: `durep`

- http://www.ubuntugeek.com/create-disk-usage-reports-with-durep.html